# Extending Bundle to add extra plist file

Tags: swift, xcode, dictionary

I imagine this is going to be simple, but I'm still learning swift.

I've created a Preferences.plist file that I want to pull in *like* Info.plist, but separate, ie:

`Bundle.main.prefsDictionary`

Or something like that ... I have a Bundle+Extension.swift file already, that contains:

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    var releaseVersionNumber: String? {
        infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
    }
}
```

So what I'm figuring I want to do is add a new var that references this extra plist file, but for all my searching, I cannot seem to find any suitable example to do this ... a lot of stuff on how to merge / append Dictionaries together, but I want to keep this separate, just easily referenceable, just like Bundle.main.infoDictionary is ...

If swift was an open source compiler, I'd pop out and find the appropriate code for 'var infoDictionary' and just copy / change that to reference the new file, but alas, that seems to be impossible.

I tried adding to my Bundle extension something as simple as:

```
   var prefsDictionary: Dictionary {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Preferences", ofType: "plist")!
        return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
   }
```

based on examples I'd found ... XCode tells me I need to add "<<#Key: Hashable#>, Any>", making it:

```
    var prefsDictionary: Dictionary<<#Key: Hashable#>, Any> {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Preferences", ofType: "plist")!
        return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
```

Leading to the next error:

```
error: Unexpected token #>, at 22:52 in XCode/app/Sources/Helpers/Bundle+Extensions.swift.
```

Even though that is what it told me to put ... so I'm sort of going around in circles, and not even sure if I'm even close to doing it right.

A good article about this would be great ... pointers always appreciated ...

Thanks ...

Comment: Note that I did figure out what I was doing wrong, and got it to work, *but* ... as is pointed out by the first Answer, what i'm using to do it is wrong in the first place.

Basically, I was returning NSDictionary, not Dictionary ... changing Dictionary -> NSDictionary allowed what I had written to work, but again, as noted, its still not "the right way"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error add the generic types and (bridge) cast the result type

```
var prefsDictionary: Dictionary<String,Any> {
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Preferences", ofType: "plist")!
    return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)! as [String:Any]
}
```

However the API `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile` is strongly discouraged in Swift. The recommended API is `PropertyListSerialization` and it's also recommended to use the URL related API

```
var prefsDictionary: Dictionary<String,Any> {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Preferences", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    return try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
}
```

But there is a still better way. Declare a struct where the members represent the keys for example

```
struct MyPrefs: Decodable {
    var versionString : String
}
```

and decode the data with `PropertyListDecoder`

```
var preferences: MyPrefs {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Preferences", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    return try! PropertyListDecoder().decode(MyPrefs.self, from: data)
}
```

Side note:

Force unwrapping the types is fine in this case. The code must not crash because the files in the application bundle are immutable at runtime. A crash reveals a **design** mistake which can be fixed instantly.

Comment: I got everything up until you talked about the MyPrefs struct ... if I do it as a Dictionary, then the Key essentially becomes the variable name, ie:

preferences["versionString"]

But if I do it as a struct as you suggest ... don't I have to modify the struct each time I add / remove a Key?   In the former, I allow the Dictionary to grow/shrink based on the plist file itself, so i can modify it but not have to modify any other code ... no?

Comment: As I said, files in the application bundle are immutable. If you change the file you have to recompile the project, and then you have to modify the struct, too. Consider that `preferences.versionString` is type safe and more convenient than `preferences["versionString"] as! String`

Comment: Will play with this,  thanks for the help ...